# How to call http from https using CORS in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, https, cors

I have a site in HTTPS that needs to call a site in HTTP (that provides JSON REST services) using CORS.

There is no problem to do that with Chrome and Firefox.

When using IE (tested from IE8 to IE10), we have "acess denied".

I am looking for a way to bypass this constrainst. I don't want to use iframe or applet.
Somebody knows a way to mix HTTP/HTTPS using CORS?

Is there an other alternative:

- maybe websockets (but we need at least HTML5 / IE10)?
- jsonp?
- JSONRequest?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do this in IE8 or IE9. See point 7, "Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page" on [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)

Websockets may help you with Firefox and IE10, but you might want to look at a server side proxy which conveys the http webservice over https.

Comment: Tk you Robert. For info I have tested JsonP but we have an alert in IE since we mix https and http contents. Of course it can be deactivated in the options of the browser.<br/> I will have a look on WebSocket but it requires a compliant server (Tomcat7 or else); so it's impacting !.<br />

Comment: About your idea to convey our http webservice over https it's one of our options. But as it's an internal access (through LAN or VPN) we think it's a pity to add a layer of encryption while we are already in a secure environment.
Note to be clearer : the browser in the LAN requests an https page (out of the LAN). In the browser this page requests an http service (in the LAN).

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? Calling http from https in IE10+ is exactly what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `http` from `https` on IE8/9, but for anyone who's interested [this link](http://www.webdbg.com/test/xdm/httptohttps.asp) shows a workaround on how you can do the opposite i.e. call `https` from `http`.